# Div clipping inside another div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get a div inside another div without it moving down to make room for text, The reason why I'm trying to do that is so I can use CSS to position them next to eachother and centered in the middle of the page [What I'm trying to accomplish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bAFLj.png)

So it looks like this in full screen mode [fullscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTih3.png)

And looks like this in windowed mode [windowed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2dsB.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I'm sorry I don't understand the relation between what you're trying to accomplish and the fullscreen and windowed screenshots. Do you want to have the divs [inside each other](https://jsfiddle.net/u1o94xg5/) or [next to each other](https://jsfiddle.net/d53jfqx8/)?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [span tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_span.asp) inside the outer div instead of another div.